# Running different actions on parent and child node

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

I'm trying to run a shake action on my gameLayer

The game layer also contains a CCSprite child that is running another action at this time.

When I run my shake action, it runs. However the effect only appears after the sprite has finished its action.

Why does this happen? Also, any solution to make both actions happen without the use of a CCSPawn?

I can run the action on the scene fine (gameLayer is a child of scene)
with the sprite also running its own action.

Comment: What actions you are running on game layer and sprite? If the actions set same properties, then one will override the other.

Comment: One is a CCShake action that moves the layer -> thats on the game layer.

The other one is a sequence of delay,block,delay,block actions -> thats on the sprite

Comment: Try to set differente tags for the actions, to see what happens

Comment: that didn't work unfortunately